# How do I get the image size from a ImageView in c#?

Tags: c#, android, imageview, size

I made a zoomable ImageView for my Android App in c#. I can pinch zoom the image and move it, but I can move it out of the screen. I want to prevent this. I need the displayed bitmap size to do that.
How do I get the bitmap size from the displayed bitmap from the ImagView in c#?
This is the code of the zoomable ImageView:

```
    class NewZoomableImageView :ImageView
{
    private static int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

  private float mPosX;
  private float mPosY;

  private float mLastTouchX;
  private float mLastTouchY;

  private float mLastGestureX;
  private float mLastGestureY;
  private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

  private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
  private static float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;

    public NewZoomableImageView(Context context, Bitmap bitmap):base(context)
  {
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(Context,new ScaleListener());
  }

  public override bool OnTouchEvent (MotionEvent e)
  {
    mScaleDetector.OnTouchEvent (e);

    //int action = e.Action;
    switch (e.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask) {
      case MotionEventActions.Down:
      if (!mScaleDetector.IsInProgress) {
        float x = e.GetX ();
        float y = e.GetY ();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;
        mActivePointerId = e.GetPointerId (0);
      }
      break;
      case MotionEventActions.Pointer1Down:
      if (mScaleDetector.IsInProgress) {
        float gx = mScaleDetector.FocusX;
        float gy = mScaleDetector.FocusY;

        mLastGestureX = gx;
        mLastGestureY = gy;
      }
      break;
      case MotionEventActions.Move:
      if (!mScaleDetector.IsInProgress) {
        int pointerIdx = e.FindPointerIndex (mActivePointerId);
        float x = e.GetX (pointerIdx);
        float y = e.GetY (pointerIdx);

        float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
        float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

          float oldXPos = mPosX;
          float oldYPos = mPosY;

        mPosX += dx;
        mPosY += dy;

        Invalidate ();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

      } else {
        float gx = mScaleDetector.FocusX;
        float gy = mScaleDetector.FocusY;

        float gdx = gx - mLastGestureX;
        float gdy = gy - mLastGestureY;

        mPosX += gdx;
        mPosY += gdy;

        Invalidate ();

        mLastGestureX = gx;
        mLastGestureY = gy;
      }
      break;
      case MotionEventActions.Up:
      mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
      break;
      case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
      mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
      break;
      case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:

      int pointerIdx2 = (int)(e.Action & MotionEventActions.PointerIndexMask) >> (int)MotionEventActions.PointerIndexShift;
      int pointerId = e.GetPointerId (pointerIdx2);

      if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
        int NewPointerIndex = pointerIdx2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
          mLastTouchX = e.GetX (NewPointerIndex);
          mLastTouchY = e.GetY (NewPointerIndex);
        mActivePointerId = e.GetPointerId (NewPointerIndex);
      }
      else{
        int TempPointerIdx = e.FindPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        mLastTouchX = e.GetX(TempPointerIdx);
        mLastTouchY = e.GetY(TempPointerIdx);
      }
      break;
    }

    return true;
  }

  protected override void OnDraw (Canvas canvas)
  {
    canvas.Save ();

    canvas.Translate (mPosX, mPosY);
    if (mScaleDetector.IsInProgress) {
      canvas.Scale (mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleDetector.FocusX, mScaleDetector.FocusY);
    } else {
      canvas.Scale (mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,mLastGestureX,mLastGestureY);
    }
    base.OnDraw (canvas);
    canvas.Restore();
  }


  private class ScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
  {
    public override bool OnScale (ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
      mScaleFactor *= detector.ScaleFactor;

      mScaleFactor = Math.Max(0.1f, Math.Min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

      return true;
    }

  }
  }
```

Comment: please provide SSCCE example.

Answer (score 1):

1) Get BitmapDrawable, for example:

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.Background;
```

2) Use 'Bitmap' property

```
int width = bd.Bitmap.Width;
int height = bd.Bitmap.Height;
int image = bd.image.len(width);
```

Comment: 1) Sytem.Invalid.CastException
Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

2) There is no Bitmap property

Comment: It is just example. And it is working, if you set Drawable background. Just try to get BitmapDrawable from your source, for example: Drawable propery.